# Example of jQuery Deferred method for executing code in order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've never used jQuery $.Deferred and so far I haven't found an example I can get my head around.

What I need is to be able to perform 3 separate tasks in order, step 1, step 2 and step 3. Step 2 should wait for step 1 to complete and step 3 should wait for step 2 to be complete before executing.

I'm trying the following but seem to be getting anywhere:

```
        var construct = new $.Deferred();

        construct.done(function() {
            console.log('Step 1');
        });

        construct.done(function() {
            setTimeout(5000);
            console.log('Step 2');
        });

        construct.done(function() {
            console.log('Step 3');
        });

        construct.resolve();
```

Does anyone have something simple working in a fiddle?

Comment: I dont think you can use setTimeout like that. It expects a function or code where your 5000 milliseconds is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout

Answer (score 2):

In order to chain [`Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)s like that, you have to use [`then`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/), and return a new [`Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/):

```
var construct = $.Deferred();

construct.then(function() {
    console.log('Step 1');
})
.then(function() {
    return $.Deferred(function (dfd) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('Step 2');
            dfd.resolve();
        }, 5000);
    });
})
.then(function() {
    console.log('Step 3');
});

construct.resolve();
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fMMsz/

Answer (score 0):

I've written something along the lines a while back for asynchronous operation but if you want it in order, you can try something like this. I have a `setInterval` to simulate long running operations.

The idea behind this is to return a `Deferred` object for each function called which will then instruct the callback defined for `done` or `fail` (if ever the case) to act based on the returned outcome.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M4mKx/)

```
var loadQueue = function() {
    var dfrQueue1 = new $.Deferred();
    var i = 0;
    var loop = window.setInterval(function() {
      ++i;
      console.log('queue 1 - running: '+i);
      if (i >= 10) {
         // pass optional param to success callback
         dfrQueue1.resolve('queue 1'); 
         clearInterval(loop);
      }
    }, 1000);

    console.log('initiating queue 1');
    return dfrQueue1.promise();
};

var loadQueue2 = function() {
    var dfrQueue2 = new $.Deferred();
    var i = 0;
    var loop = window.setInterval(function() {
      ++i;
      console.log('queue 2 - running: '+i);
      if (i >= 5) {
          // pass optional param to success callback
          dfrQueue2.resolve('queue 2');
          clearInterval(loop);
      }
    }, 1000);

    console.log('initiating queue 2');
    return dfrQueue2.promise();
};

var t = loadQueue().done(loadQueue2);
```